# Difficult array sort order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => array("src" => "foo-21.gif"),
    1 => array("src" => "bar-short.gif"), 
    2 => array("src" => "baz-1.gif"), 
    3 => array("src" => "whatever.gif"), 
    4 => array("src" => "some-long.gif"), 
    5 => array("src" => "xyz.gif"), 
);
```

The value in the `src` element can be anything.

However there will only be max. one element containing `short` (here it is element 1) and only max. one elment containing `long` (here it is element 4). They can be anywhere in the array. Or not present at all.

What I need to do now is:

- The element with `src` containing `short` must be first if present
- The element conaining `long` must be last  if present
- The order in between does not matter.

So the example would look like this:

```
array(
    0 => array("src" => "bar-short.gif"), // containing "short" = first
    1 => array("src" => "foo-21.gif"), 
    2 => array("src" => "baz-1.gif"), 
    3 => array("src" => "whatever.gif"), 
    4 => array("src" => "xyz.gif"), 
    5 => array("src" => "some-long.gif"), // containing "long" = last
);
```

How would I do this? `usort` does not seem like a good idea here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your array is `$list`:

```
function short_long_sort($a, $b)
{
    $short_str = '-short';
    $long_str = '-long';
    if (strpos($a['src'], $short_str)) return -1;
    if (strpos($b['src'], $short_str)) return 1;
    if (strpos($a['src'], $long_str)) return 1;
    if (strpos($b['src'], $long_str)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

usort($list, 'short_long_sort');
print_r($list);
```

Comment: Edit to replace preg_match() with strpos(). Everybody knows SO loves `(?!regex)`.

Comment: Nice! Did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

`usort()` could actually work just fine here; return -1 if the first argument has "short" and/or the second argument has "long", 1 if vice versa, and 0 (or anything, really) if neither is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you don't need to sort anything if you just track which elements have "short" and "long" when you input them, then eg:

```
process($arr->[$short]);
for ($i=0; $i < @$arr; $i++) {
  process($arr->[$i]) if (($i != $short) && ($i != $long));
}
process($arr->[$long]);
```